# K&R Table Lookup Code

Tags: c

Trying to understand the following code for a linked list/struct implementation of a simple hash lookup algorithm as discussed in K&R:

```
struct nlist *lookup(char *);
char *strdup(char *);
/* install: put (name, defn) in hashtab */
struct nlist *install(char *name, char *defn)
{
    struct nlist *np;
    unsigned hashval;
    if ((np = lookup(name)) == NULL) { /* not found */
        np = (struct nlist *) malloc(sizeof(*np));
        if (np == NULL || (np->name = strdup(name)) == NULL)
            return NULL;
        hashval = hash(name);
        np->next = hashtab[hashval];
        hashtab[hashval] = np;
} else /* already there */
        free((void *) np->defn); /*free previous defn */
if ((np->defn = strdup(defn)) == NULL)
    return NULL;
return np;
```

A few things I don't understand. This line:

```
np = (struct nlist *) malloc(sizeof(*np));
```

occurs after the if statement assigns the value `lookup(name)` to np. So what does this malloc assignment do? Does it re-initialize the value? If so, what's up with the following line?

```
if ((np = lookup(name)) == NULL)
```

Won't it always be NULL if malloc re-initializes it? Or does malloc simply allocate the memory without messing with the value that was assigned to np earlier? If that's the case, then why does it check again if np is NULL if it already does that in the initial if statement?

When it comes to the `np->next` code, I'm totally lost. Why is np->next seemingly referring to itself?

Here is the code for the lookup() function:

```
/* lookup: look for s in hashtab */
    struct nlist *lookup(char *s)
    {
    struct nlist *np;
    for (np = hashtab[hash(s)]; np != NULL; np = np->next)
        if (strcmp(s, np->name) == 0)
            return np; /* found */
    return NULL; /* not found */
}
```

Here is the nlist struct:

```
struct nlist { /* table entry: */
    struct nlist *next; /* next entry in chain */
    char *name; /* defined name */
    char *defn; /* replacement text */
};
```

Comment: You might want to start lower. This is a somewhat more experienced example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
if ((np = lookup(name)) == NULL)
```

Does two things. First, it assigns the result of `lookup(name)` to `np`. Second, it tests the result of that assignment to see if it is `NULL`.

If that `if` statement is true, that means `np` is `NULL`, so they go on to `malloc` a value for it.

Now, if `malloc` fails to allocate memory, it returns `NULL`. `strdup` internally calls `malloc`, so that's why the next line

```
if (np == NULL || (np->name = strdup(name)) == NULL)
```

is making sure that both allocations that just happened succeeded.

---

First of all, the hash table looks like this:  It is a table of pointers to linked lists. The indices into the array are hash values:

[image]

Now when we add a new entry:

```
    np->next = hashtab[hashval];
    hashtab[hashval] = np;
```

`hashtab[hashval]` is already the beginning of a list of entries with that same hash. It could be NULL. This code adds the new entry to the *front* of the list! So we point the new entry's `next` pointer at the existing list, and set the hash table to point to the new entry so it is now first.

[image]

They add the node to the front of the list, so that an insertion is an O(1) operation.

Comment: Thanks, that clears up almost everything. Regarding the pointer to itself thing, though, it's odd because the book introduces this idiom for iterating over the linked list: `for (ptr = head; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next)`. It seems like this would create an infinite loop because the pointer never points to NULL. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hmm, I share your confusion. I guess I'd have to see the whole thing to understand.

Comment: I updated the code with the lookup() function in case you're interested.

Comment: @user1427661 I updated my answer so it is actually right, in case you're interested :-)

Comment: Awesome! It's all coming together now.